# Building a PPI network graph from differentially expressed genes and obtaining an interaction file for cytoHubba

Tags: bioinformatics, cytoscape

I used GEO2R to obtain three Excel files each of which contains a column of differentially expressed genes. I would like to combine these three columns into one column, select a sufficient number of genes in order to build a PPI network graph that does not resemble an impenetrable ball of yarn, then use the interaction file(?) for use with the cytoHubba app in order to obtain the top 10 genes of clinical interest. I believe I can accomplish the first task, but the PPI and interaction file tasks are slightly elusive. Any constructive feedback would be most welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because more suitable at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ or https://www.biostars.org/

Answer (score 0):

Already answered on the Cytoscape helpdesk: https://groups.google.com/g/cytoscape-helpdesk/c/GWp0QbTJf2o?hl=en_US%2F